# a function which determines if a given point(x, y) is in the mandelbrot set or not

Tags: mandelbrot

So given any point (a + ib), the function will return 1 if it is in the mandelbrot set or 0 if not for n amount of iterations.

I'm having difficulties trying to code this function, especially with the complex numbers. Can anyone help me or give some advice for me to start?

So far I can only think of a way to determine if a real number (any x, y = 0) is in the mandelbrot set.

EDIT: Sorry forgot to say that I'm coding in C, I'm looking for some psuedocode ideas mostly though.

Comment: See if [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4066068/some-help-rendering-the-mandelbrot-set) is of any help to you.

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: @jonsca thanks, I'm having trouble with splitting the two equations though.

Comment: Actually, worked it out. You're the best and I love you jonsca.

Answer (score 1):

The Wikipedia page on the set has some pseudocode that does the basic job, and hints at some of the many directions in which you can take such a project. Understanding complex math is the key; it is traditional to keep the real and imaginary components of a complex as a pair of doubles and implement whatever operations you need on them by hand or as macros. (These days you can use the `complex` type if your compiler speaks C99, but where's the fun in that...? :-) )

Answer (score 0):

You need to repeatedly square and add a complex number:

```
double a = real input component;
double b = imag input component;

double zReal = a;
double zImag = b;
for(int i = 0; i< LIMIT; i++){
   double temp = zReal;
   zReal = zReal * zReal - zImag * zImag;
   zImag = 2 * temp * zImag;
   if(zReal * zReal + zImag * zImag > 4){
      return 0;
   }
}
return 1;
```